# Change the backgroudn and foreground color when hovering over the content in a dropdown menu in HTML

Tags: html, css

This is my code right now im trying to change the background and font color when hovering over something within the dropdown menu i'm unsure where to place in the code.I'm unsure if i have to edit within the CSS or HTML code.

Here is my HTML

```
<body>
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="dropbtn"><b>Some Colleges at <br>MSU</b></button>
<div class="dropdown-content">
<a href="#"><center><b>College of Math and Sciences</b></center></a>
<a href="#"><center><b>Business School</b></center></a>
<a href="#"><center><b>College of Humanities and Social Sciences</b> 
</center></a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
 <button class="dropbtn"><b>Departments in <br>CSAM</b></button>
<div class="dropdown-content">
<a href="#"><center><b>Biology</b></center></a>
<a href="#"><center><b>Computer Scince</b></center></a>
<a href="#"><center><b>Math</b></center></a>
<a href="#"><center><b>Chemistry</b></center></a>
<a href="#"><center><b>Earth and Environment Studies</b></center></a>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Here is my CSS

```
<style>
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: black; color:white;}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: red;}

.dropdown-content a {
color: white;
padding: 2px 10px;
text-decoration: none;
border: 1px solid blue;
display: block;
}

.dropbtn {
background-color: red;
color: cyan;
padding: 2px;
font-size: 16px;
border: 2px solid blue;
}

.dropdown {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: black;
min-width: 120px;

z-index: 1;
}
</style>
```

Comment: You'll probably want to target the desired element with a `:hover` selector. Which element is dependent on your HTML, and if you post that you'll be able to get more specific suggestions.

Comment: okay thank you i added my html code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right code, it's just not visibly doing anything because the `:hover` colour is the same as the colour you've set in other classes.

This line: `.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: black; color:white;}` *is* changing your colours on hover, just to the same thing. Change these colours and I think you'll find it achieves the effect you desire.

Answer (score 0):

.dropdown-content a:hover { background-color: add your color; color: add your color;}